# Pointwise and uniform convergence of ${\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{2n}\right )^{4n^2}x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I want to check the pointwise and uniform convergence of the below power series.

- $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{2n}\right )^{4n^2}x^n}$

We have that \begin{equation*}\sqrt[n]{\left (1+\frac{1}{2n}\right )^{4n^2}}=\left (1+\frac{1}{2n}\right )^{4n}=\left [\left (1+\frac{1}{2n}\right )^{2n} \right ]^2\to e^2=\frac{1}{R} \Rightarrow R=\frac{1}{e^2}\end{equation*}
So we have pointwise convergence for $|x|<\frac{1}{e^2}$.

We check also the boundaries $x=-\frac{1}{e^2}$ and $x=\frac{1}{e^2}$.

At $x=-\frac{1}{e^2}$ we have $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{2n}\right )^{4n^2}\left (-\frac{1}{e^2}\right )^n}$.

At $x=\frac{1}{e^2}$ we have $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{2n}\right )^{4n^2}\left (\frac{1}{e^2}\right )^n}$.

How do we check these series?

Comment: As $(1+\frac1{2n})^{2n}<e$, there is some hope for convergence at $x=\frac1{e^2}$.

Comment: So we have that $$\left (1+\frac1{2n}\right )^{2n}<e \Rightarrow \left (\left (1+\frac1{2n}\right )^{2n}\right )^2<e^2\Rightarrow \left (1+\frac1{2n}\right )^{4n}<e^2\\ \Rightarrow \left (1+\frac1{2n}\right )^{4n}\cdot \frac{1}{e^{2n}}<e^2\cdot \frac{1}{e^{2n}}\Rightarrow \left (1+\frac1{2n}\right )^{4n}\cdot \frac{1}{e^{2n}}< \frac{1}{e^{2n-2}}$$ Now we have to show that $\sum \frac{1}{e^{2n-2}}$ converges, right? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Nope, the exponent is $4n^2$.

Comment: $T_{\infty} = \pm 1$, so doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\ln \left[\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{4n^2} \left( \frac{1}{e^2}\right)^n \right] = 4n^2 \ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2n}\right) - 2n = 4n^2 \left( \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{8n^2} + o\left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) - 2n$$
$$= -\frac{1}{2} + o \left( 1\right)$$

So
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{4n^2} \left( \frac{1}{e^2}\right)^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$

so both $$\sum \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{4n^2} \left( \frac{-1}{e^2}\right)^n \quad \text{ and } \quad \sum \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{4n^2} \left( \frac{1}{e^2}\right)^n$$ diverge.

Comment: How did you conclude that the two series diverge? I got stuck right now.

Comment: If a series converges, its general term has to tend to $0$.

Comment: I see!! Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar You are welcome :)